# How to get html hidden field value inside c#?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I used a hidden field inside li tag in c#. please help me to get the value of hidden field in it..

```
   public string text="";
   for (var i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
   {             
        text += "<li class=''>";
        text += "<input type='hidden' id='hid_dtlid' name='hid_dtlid' value='" + dt.Rows[i]["Spindtlid"].ToString() + "'/>";
        text += "</li>";   
   }
```

Comment: Can you please clear me about your requirement. What I guess is you are adding dynamic controls `li` to your `aspx` page. and when you click on any of the `li` tag, in codebehind you need the value of hidden field inside it. Correct me if I am wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

All the name attributes of the hidden field elements should be unique. This can be accessed on the server (provided they are all nested in a html form element). You simply make you use of `Request.Form` collection.

Say below is what your markup rendered by asp.net looks like

```
<form method="post" action="foo.aspx">
   <!-- other stuff -->

   <input type="hidden" name="fooField" value="bar"/>

   <!-- more other stuff -->
</form>
```

Note that this is not an element marked with `runat="server"`. And even if its so, you wouldn't know the difference unless you inspect carefully.

On the server-side you can access it as follows:

```
var value = Request.Form["fooField"]; //stores "bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

In jquery it would be:

```
thevalue = $('#hid_dtlid').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're loking for server side on postboack `Request.Form["hid_dtlid"]`

Asp.net is nothing but a series of request and responsonses with some fancy absctration on top. The basics are still accessible through the `Request` and `Response` objects

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not added these hidden fields as a C# hidden field object hence they will not be available directly.
However with post back these fields will be sent by the browser client in the header in Request.Form collection which can be extracted like below:

```
var hiddenElements = Request.Form["hid_dtlid"] ;//it will return an array of fields with name hid_dtlid
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to get the cotnrol value directly in c# you need to set **runat="server"** for that control asp.net **web forms**.

```
<input  runat="server" type='hidden' id='hid_dtlid' name='hid_dtlid' value='" + dt.Rows[i]["Spindtlid"].ToString() + "' />
```

when it will post data you can get

```
var hiddenElements = Request.Form["ID"]
```